# trying to send schema to ledger(trying to make identifcation system using hyperledger indy)

Tags: python, hyperledger, hyperledger-indy, indy-node

```
"Schema Builder" -> Send "Device Profile" Schema to Ledger
{"reqId":1683198357199119479,"identifier":"2qzghpxTM5H81hUbYFmPR4","reason":"client request invalid: UnauthorizedClientRequest('Rule for this action is: 1 TRUSTEE signature is required OR 1 STEWARD signature is required OR 1 ENDORSER signature is required\\nFailed checks:\\nConstraint: 1 TRUSTEE signature is required, Error: Not enough TRUSTEE signatures\\nConstraint: 1 STEWARD signature is required, Error: Not enough STEWARD signatures\\nConstraint: 1 ENDORSER signature is required, Error: Not enough ENDORSER signatures',)","op":"REJECT"}





STEP5 - theCredDefGenerator creates Device Profile Credential Definition


================================
--------------------------------------------------
"theCredDefGenerator" -> Get "device profile " Schema from Ledger
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 177, in <module>
    loop.run_until_complete(run())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/asyncio/base_events.py", line 484, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "main.py", line 151, in run
    (theCredDefGenerator['deviceprofile_schema_id'], theCredDefGenerator['deviceprofile_schema']) = await ledger.parse_get_schema_response(get_schema_response)
  File "/home/amit_jatola/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/indy/ledger.py", line 568, in parse_get_schema_response
    parse_get_schema_response.cb)
indy.error.LedgerNotFound
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: little more explanation about what you are trying to do might be useful

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error from the ledger:

```
client request invalid: UnauthorizedClientRequest('Rule for this action is: 1 TRUSTEE signature is required OR 1 STEWARD signature is required OR 1 ENDORSER signature is required
```

You either need to endorse this transaction, or create this transaction from an account with the correct permissions, such as a trustee or steward.